# How to automate deployment of React app to VPS?

Tags: reactjs, deployment

I'm using Ruby on Rails for the back end and I deploy it using Capistrano. As for the front end I'm using React, I couldn't find a way to automate the deployment of React just like Capistrano. I don't want use github every time I update the front end by cloning to the VPS. Is there away to automate this process?